# Setting width for label.adjustSizeToText() in PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, labeling

If I set size of label with `label.adjustSizeToText()` using PyQGIS, it sets widths randomly. I would like to set width myself, but let it automatically change the height so that all text is fitting.

How can I set width manually rather than randomly?

```
for labeldata in places.places:
    label = QgsLayoutItemLabel(layout)
    print(labeldata["name"])
    label.setText(labeldata["name"])
    #label.setFont(QFont("Helvetica", 30))
    text_format = QgsTextFormat()
    text_format.setFont(QFont("Arial"))
    text_format.setSize(30)
    label.setTextFormat(text_format)
    label.attemptMove(QgsLayoutPoint(50,y, QgsUnitTypes.LayoutMillimeters))
    label.adjustSizeToText()
    #y += label.sizeWithUnits().height()
    y += label.boundingRect().height()
    layout.addLayoutItem(label)
```

Places contains list of place names, all containing dictionary item containing the "name" field. Depending on length of text, it wraps them from random places.

Answer (score 0):

To set a fixed width for the label, you can use the [`attemptResize()`](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.30/core/QgsLayoutItem.html#qgis.core.QgsLayoutItem.attemptResize) method.

```py
y = 10

for labeldata in places.places:
    label = QgsLayoutItemLabel(layout)
    label.setText(labeldata["name"])
    text_format = QgsTextFormat()
    text_format.setFont(QFont("Arial"))
    text_format.setSize(30)
    label.setTextFormat(text_format)
    label.attemptMove(QgsLayoutPoint(50, y, QgsUnitTypes.LayoutMillimeters))
    label.adjustSizeToText()
    y += label.boundingRect().height()
    
    # set a fixed width for the label
    label.attemptResize(QgsLayoutSize(50, label.boundingRect().height()))
    
    layout.addLayoutItem(label)
```

[image]

Comment: But how this recalculates the height? The old rectangle of the bounding box is not suitable, it's just one line. I think this way, the setting for height dependant of width will not take an effect.

Comment: Your question is *"How can I set width manually?"*